# 2 SELECT STATEMENTS in one BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a calculated field "Workday" which is working fine and using this calculated field I am trying to create another calculated field "FTE" which is giving me an error

What is the correct way to write this in BQ

My query:

```
(select((select count(*) from unnest(generate_date_array(date_trunc('2021-05-25', month), last_day('2021-05-25', month ))) day where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7))) as Workday),
(select SAFE_DIVIDE(AMOUNT, SAFE_MULTIPLY(MAX(Workday,(7.35))))) as FTE,
```

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Comment: Unrecognized name: Workday at ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe envelope original query into another one?

```
select workday
from (
  select (...) as workday
  from ...
)
```

Also `SAFE_MULTIPLY` should have 2 parameters and `MAX` should have 1 parameter

Comment: (select count(*) from unnest(generate_date_array(date_trunc(CALENDAR_DATE, month), last_day(CALENDAR_DATE, month ))) day
where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)) as Workdays,
(SELECT SAFE_DIVIDE(AMOUNT,(SAFE_MULTIPLY(Workdays,7.35)))) as FTE

Comment: Workdays from previous select is not recognised, if i replace workdays with a static value like 21 the query works fine